# C# Displaying String of ObservableCollection on event CollectionChanged

Tags: c#, event-handling, observablecollection

I'm just learning events in C# and was given the following example in a tutorial. My question is how I can display the contents of the string added/removed in my event handler.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SubscribeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var coll = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            // TODO: subscribe to an event here
            coll.CollectionChanged += coll_CollectionChanged;

            coll.Add("Big Mac");
            coll.Add("Filet 'O Fish");
            coll.Add("Quarter Pounder");
            coll.Add("French Fries");
            coll.Remove("Filet 'O Fish");

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static void coll_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Does not do what I want it to.
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(e.NewItems));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert.ToString is not magic (or even that clever).. You will have to loop through `e.NewItems` yourself and print each value.

Comment: Thank you =). Right after I posted (as per usual) I figured out that I could iterate through a list of the newItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Observable Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [The Collection Changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) and [The Event Args](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation are pretty straight forward.

In the changed event you have the properties `NewItems` and `OldItems` (among others) that contain the newly added or removed objects from the collection. Now these are a simple `IList` (not to be confused with `IList<T>`) so you have to do some casting. As we know the collection is a string we would expect the `NewItems` or the `OldItems` collection to contain string values.

Now these properties are `null` if they are not applicable. ie. In a `Add` method (or [action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction(v=vs.110).aspx)) the `OldItems` property will be null. Therefore if you just want to print the changes try below.

```
static void coll_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();

    //added items
    if (e.NewItems != null)
        items.AddRange(e.NewItems.OfType<string>());

    ///old items
    if (e.OldItems != null)
        items.AddRange(e.OldItems.OfType<string>());

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items));
}
```

Full Changed Code: Again this doesnt worry about the action just prints the results.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var coll = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        // TODO: subscribe to an event here
        coll.CollectionChanged += coll_CollectionChanged;

        coll.Add("Big Mac");
        coll.Add("Filet 'O Fish");
        coll.Add("Quarter Pounder");
        coll.Add("French Fries");
        coll.Remove("Filet 'O Fish");

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void coll_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        //added items
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            items.AddRange(e.NewItems.OfType<string>());

        ///old items
        if (e.OldItems != null)
            items.AddRange(e.OldItems.OfType<string>());

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing something like this after your help: '        
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.Action, item);
                }
            }

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.Action, item);
                }
            }
        '

Comment: Answer still valid. Just wanted to mention you need to include `System.Linq`.